# Multi-part identifier could not be bound SQL

Tags: sql

Can you tell me what is wrong with this query?

```
select as_epossvol.stkcode, as_currsale.stkcode 
from as_currsale 
join as_epossale on as_currsale.epos_id = as_epossale.epos_id
```

I cannot figure it out, thank you

Comment: Where's `as_epossvol` supposed to come from?

Comment: What's `as_epossvol` and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT pos.stkcode, cur.stkcode 
FROM as_currsale cur
JOIN as_epossale pos ON pos.epos_id = cur.epos_id
```

Does it return the same error?

Comment: How do you know where `stkcode` is coming from

Comment: FROM as_currsale cur

Comment: Yes but you have `pos.stkcode ` with `pos` being `as_epossale `. How do you know this column exists in this table

Comment: I just inverted because Im used to JOIN like this...nothing else.